# What does "in prose" means in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Now that you have identified what the scholar is arguing and how the argument is constructed, you will write a summary, in prose, of the argument in your own words.

Does the instruction means that we now write a summary of the argument in our own words?

What is the "in prose" emphasizing here?

Comment: I suppose they don't want their students to spout poetry in that assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction is directing you to write in ordinary English (as opposed to poetry or dot points, for example).

Definition of prose from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prose

1 a :the ordinary language people use in speaking or writing
b :a literary medium distinguished from poetry especially by its greater irregularity and variety of rhythm and its closer correspondence to the patterns of everyday speech